# Access Website & Download files from a Server

Tags: html, excel, vba, http

I am trying to write a VBA macro to download files from our companies server. In order to download the files, I look for their number of our my excel list. E.G. the number is "250". Then I need to search for "250" on the website and then get the objectID of the file.
So the links of the download document looks like this :

```
https://plm.corp.int:10090/enovia/tvc-action/downloadMultipleFiles?objectId=***4706.39075.61185.44166***&object=250
```

4706.39075.61185.44166 this number is what I need to find for every of my numbers from excel, in order to edit the download link and get the files.

[image]

in the image you can see how it looks in the source code of the website...
Now I have absolutely no idea how I can extract such data our of source code in VBA

Comment: On the screenshot is no 250. But it is needed to identify the correct code segment. Please post a larger HTML excerpt showing the number you want query from Excel. At best as HTML snippet and not as screenshot

Comment: @Zwenn Please look at my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zwenn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Eix.png)

the E2**** is the number out of excel, that i am searching for on the platform.
The 4706 number form my original question, is the unique ID of every E2***number.

Comment: You show two very different parts of the HTML code. If there is a connection between the two, then the first must be in the structure of the second. Otherwise you cannot deduce the value from the number. Please no more screenshots. Please enough HTML code as code snippet!